# iOS getting `biometryNotAvailable` error when device supports biometry

Tags: ios, swift, localauthentication

If user doesn't opts to use Face ID when presented with permission dialog, I'm getting `biometryNotAvailable` error on calling `canEvaluatePolicy(_:error:)`.
As per apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/laerror/code/2867584-biometrynotavailable), we should get it when device doesn't supports biometry. Im testing it on iPhone 12 Pro, Xcode 14, iOS 16 using `deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics` policy. Below is the code Im using:

```
var canEvaluatePolicy: Bool {
    var error: NSError?
    guard context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) else {
        print("\(error?.localizedDescription)") // Prints "Biometry is not available."
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Shouldn't I get `biometryNotEnrolled` in this case? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, biometry not enrolled means exactly what it says. Biometrics are available to your app but the user has not set them up. In the case where permission is denied then biometrics are just not available to your app and even though your app  might "know" that the hardware exists your app is not permitted to know anything about the state of biometrics on the device and the appropriate response is to proceed as if the device does not have biometrics capability

Answer (score 1):

In any project that uses biometrics, you should include the NSFaceIDUsageDescription key in your app’s Info.plist file.

If you accidentally have removed the permission on your iPhone 12 Pro, try  Settings > Face ID & Passcode > Use Face ID For > Other Apps.

On the simulator, this option doesn't exist and your only option is Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy

Make sure that FaceID is enabled on your iPhone.

Comment: Thanks @Luca-Petra. plist addition is already there. I just wasn't able to understand this error correctly. Paul's answer above really helps to understand it.